# Oracle SQL - Retorno do primeiro registro entre duas datas

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho essa query:

```
SELECT codigo_usuario, dataproducao 
FROM tbproducao
WHERE
dataproducao >= to_date('01/02/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
and dataproducao <= to_date('30/03/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and
```

É o resultado vem como esperado, retornado todos os registros que estão entre as datas informadas, exemplo:

```
codigo_usuario | dataproducao 
 -------------------
   5      01/02/2013
 -------------------
   8      03/02/2013
```

O codigo_usuario "5" retornado na consulta a cima tem outro registro com a dataproducao = 05/10/2012, que foi o seu primeiro registro na tabela.

É agora vem o problema, não consigo fazer com que a consulta a cima não retorne o codigo 5, pós quero que a consulta retorne entre as datas informadas os registros que tiverem seu primeiro registro naquele intervalo. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Sorack, editei a pergunta colocando o nome real da tabela. Os dados de exemplo já ta no exemplo. Facilita?

Comment: Sorack, exatamente.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `EXISTS` em conjunto com `NOT`:

```
SELECT p.codigo_usuario,
      p.data_producao
  FROM tbproducao p
WHERE p.data_producao BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/02/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30/03/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tbproducao p2
                  WHERE p2.codigo_usuario = p.codigo_usuario
                    AND p2.data_producao < TO_DATE('01/02/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

> [`EXISTS` Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm)
>
> An `EXISTS` condition tests for existence of rows in a `subquery`.

Em tradução livre:

> Uma condição `EXISTS` testa a existência de linhas em uma `subquery`.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: @PauloGonçalves Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente desta forma:

```
SELECT      T.*
FROM        tabela  T
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT  codigo
                    ,   dataproducao
                    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codigo ORDER BY dataproducao) AS rn
                FROM    tabela
            )       T2 ON T2.codigo = T.codigo AND T2.rn = 1
WHERE       T.dataproducao  BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013-02-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
        AND TO_DATE('2013-03-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
        AND T2.dataproducao BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013-02-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
        AND TO_DATE('2013-03-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

A ideia foi colocar uma consulta que obtesse o número de linha em cada um dos grupos de código e depois, no `LEFT JOIN`, apanhar apenas os de `número = 1`.

De seguida comparar as datas nos registos da consulta principal + o da subconsulta com apenas as datas do primeiro registo temporal.